# Error of Lagrange Interpolating polynomial is zero for polynomials of low degree

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

Let $f$ be a function defined on the interval $[x_0 −h, x_0, x_0 +h]$, and $f \in C^3[x_0 −h, x_0 +h]$.

Let $h$ be the Lagrange interpolation polynomial of $f$ at the nodes $x = x_0 − h$, $x_0$, $x_0 + h$.

If we approximate the derivative $f'(x_0)$ by $h'(x_0)$, why is it true that the above approximation is exact if $f$ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $2$?

Comment: How many parabolas can one draw through three points?

Comment: two?  (if you mean there is only one line passing through them)

Comment: Only one. Because if you had two quadratic polynomials attaining the same values in three points, their difference would have three roots. Use this to conclude that $h\equiv f$.